# How do I start an app using cerberus start app func or..?

Tags: android, linux, directory

I'm a noob btw so I try doing thing the way I think it will work which didn't so I need your help. There this website from cerberus app. I tried to start app by typing the path to the app. Send the command throught the site built-in sms toward my phone number but still will not start. There also a shell that launches from the site that show something like the linux cmd. These are the path I tried execute.                                   system/data/app/com.android.chrome_6.apk                                                                          chrome.apk
data/app/com.android.chrome_6.apk. 
My phone is an Samsung Galaxy Avant.

Answer (score 0):

You wilk need to know the actual package name. For example you can open the system settings app with com.android.settings.

You can find  the package name by using an app called Uninstaller Pro app from play store. It will show you the package name as ID.